# Why don't Black Americans vote Republican?

Tags: voting

It was the Republican Party that enacted the Emancipation Proclamation, which freed the slaves, yet Black Americans seem to overwhelmingly vote Democratic, why?

> ### Percentage of black votes for the democratic party from 1976 to 2012
>
> 1976 - 83% of black vote
>  1980 - 83% of black vote
>  1984 - 91%
>   of black vote
>  1988 - 89% of black vote
>  1992 - 83% of black
>   vote
>  1996 - 84% of black vote
>  2000 - 90% of black vote
>   2004 - 88% of black vote
>  2008 - 95% of black vote
>  2012 - 93%
>   of black vote